# Qual maneira mais eficiente para formatar a saída do código para o usuário?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Qual a maneira mais eficiente para formatar a saída do meu código? É um exercício clássico da internet, porém gostaria de aperfeiçoá-lo.

Quero deixar as barras de "limite", (`|`) sempre com o mesmo padrão, mas ao excutar o código, dependendo do resultado elas se distorcem como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
from os import system

def calculo():
  peso_peixe = float(input('Informe o peso do peixe (em Kgs): '))
  if peso_peixe > 50:
    excesso = peso_peixe - 50
    print('|---------------------------------------------------------|')
    print('|                                                         |')
    print('|Peso do peixe exedeu o limite de 50kgs em {:.2f} Kgs      |'.format(excesso))
    print('|                                                         |')
    print('|O valor da Multa é R$ 4,00 por Kg exedido                |')
    print('|                                                         |')
    multa = excesso * 4.0
    print('|Deverá ser pago uma multa de R${:.2f}                    |'.format(multa))
    print('|---------------------------------------------------------|')
  else:
    print('|--------------------------------------------------------------|')
    print('|                                                              |')
    print('|O peso informado para o peixe é {:.2f} Kgs, não gerando multa! |'.format(peso_peixe))
    print('|                                                              |')
    print('|--------------------------------------------------------------|')
    

calculo()

while True:
  continuar = str(input('\nDESEJA EXECUTAR NOVAMENTE? (S/N) ')).upper()
  system('cls||clear')
  if continuar != 'S':
    break
  calculo()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A mini-linguagem de formatação de strings usada pelo "format"  pelas f-strings permitem especificar extamente a largura de saída de qualquer string, e como completar os espaços faltantes.

Então, se eu quero que qualquer número tenha exatamente 7 carácteres de largura, preenchidos por espaços, posso fazer:

```py
In [51]: print("|{:7.2f}|\n|{:7.04f}|".format(2.34567, 2.34567))                                          
|   2.35|
| 2.3457|
```

A documentação completa está aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language (e não é a documentação mais fácil de ler do mundo, desculpe)

Com isso você conseguiria controlar as larguras dos números no seu exemplo, e tornar as barrinhas alinhadas - mas está longe de ser a *melhor* forma de faz isso.
De repente até é a mais "eficiente" depende do critério que você usar para "eficiente" (pode ser a mais rápida de executar por um fator de perto de 0.5%, por exemplo).

## pensando modularmente

Mas isso implica em que  *Todo* o seu programa, em *cada* saída que você for fazer para o usuario, vai ter que ficar contando os tamanhos e ajustando a formatação. Você ja tem que fazer isso acima.

A melhor coisa é você criar uma *função* que "enfeita"  a saída como quiser, e simplesmente passa uma lista de strings para ela.  Aí você deixa o *computador* fazer as contas de quanto precisa adicionar de espaços antes e depois de cada linha de texto para colocar as molduras para você.

Isso além de facilitar muito sua vida, permite que no "núcleo" do seu programa você só precise se preocupar em gerar os resultados - e em outra parte, se preocupa com a apresentação - é o mesmo princípio usado há mais de 20 anos quando decidiram que a apresentação de páginas web seria controlada pelo CSS - uma linguagem completamente distinta do HTML, que só se preocupa em dizer "o que é o quê".

Sem fazer nada muito sofisticado - apenas uma função que permita desenhar molduras como a que você já desenha, o código pode ficar assim:

```py
def imprime_formatado(texto, largura=60, moldura="|_+"):
    vertical, horizontal, canto = moldura
    print(f"{canto}{horizontal * (largura - 2)}{canto}")
    
    # cria uma copia da lista de strings, para não alterar a original, e acrescenta
    # uma linha em branco no começo e uma no final, para espaçamento:
    
    texto = texto[:]
    texto.insert(0, '')
    texto.append('')
    for linha in texto:
        print (f"{vertical}{linha:{largura-2}s}{vertical}")
    print(f"{canto}{horizontal * (largura - 2)}{canto}")
    

def calculo():
    peso_peixe = float(input('Informe o peso do peixe (em Kgs): '))
    if peso_peixe > 50:
        excesso = peso_peixe - 50
        multa = excesso * 4.0
        texto = [
            f'|Peso do peixe exedeu o limite de 50kgs em {excesso:.2f} Kgs',
            '',
            'O valor da Multa é R$ 4,00 por Kg excedido',
            '',
            f'Deverá ser pago uma multa de R${multa:.2f}',
        ]
    else:
        texto = [f'O peso informado para o peixe é {peso_peixe:.2f} Kgs, não gerando multa!']
    
    imprime_formatado(texto)
```

Perceba que mesmo numa função simplesinha dessas, fica fácil trocar a moldura - se quero uma mensagem com uma moldua com "*" em vez de "|_+" é só chamar com `moldura="***"` - e dá pra sofisticar muito mais, sem interir com a lógica que é o "núlcleo" do seu programa: o cálculo da multa, etc...

Em tempo: mudei as chamadas ao método "format" para o uso de "f-strings" - você põe o prefixo "f" e pode colocar diretamente expressões em Python dentro das { } na string, incluindo variáveis- isso é muito mais fácil e comodo de usar que chamar o ".format", que em gera só vai aparecer em documentação e livros escritos antes de da versão "3.6" do Python existir ou estar mais difundida.

Comment: Resposta brilhante. Só não voto de novo pq já votei. Não existe um módulo pronto para isso em python?

Comment: tem alguma coisa - mas não tem como a linguagem "adivinhar" quanto cada um vai querer enfeitar a saida de um programa simples para o terminal.  O módulo "textwrap" da biblioteca padrão tem alguma funcionalidade para formatar texto assim. Mas em geral, se um programa ficar mais sério, ele vai ter uma interface gráfica, ou uma interface web - e as funcionalidades de formatar texto vem junto com o framework usado para a interface.

Comment: Para imprimir molduras no terminal, tem o "curses" qu enão funciona em Windows, ou dá pra construir uma interface usando um projeto como o "terminedia" ou "python prompt toolkit"